# Вывести общий бал React (input checkbox)

Tags: reactjs

Получается ситуация такая что есть опрос (по баллам) нужно вывести общий бал при выборе оценок от 1 до 4. 8-12 вопросов и везде варианты 1-4. На бэк уходят после submit и не отслеживается кто какой вариант выбрал какого вопроса (ActionType) и получается **нужно** отследить ответы каждого вопроса и вывести общий балл.
  Как это сделать?

```
 {id: "06263456-e22f-4541-9b21-ee77e7c106a4", title: "test", createDate: "2019-01-16T09:31:37.247",…}
    questions: [{id: "4d27fd0d-97a1-46ce-95e9-c66b200a453c", text: "vopros 1 ", minAnswersQuantity: 1,…},…]
    0: {id: "4d27fd0d-97a1-46ce-95e9-c66b200a453c", text: "vopros 1 ", minAnswersQuantity: 1,…}
    canAttachFile: false
    currentUserAnswerVariants: []
    group: {name: "1", id: "a9948d62-fe09-445c-8079-b637f5bd91bf", createdDate: "2018-10-12T11:17:20.54"}
    id: "a9948d62-fe09-445c-8079-b637f5bd91bf"
    maxAnswersQuantity: 1
    minAnswersQuantity: 1
    text: "vopros 1 "
    totalAnswers: 1
    variants: [,…]
    0: {id: "b080d14c-9b3d-4569-9b74-dc1a50fab731", text: "1", maxAnswersQuantity: 0, userAnswersQuantity: 0,…}
canAnswer: true
id: "b080d14c-9b3d-4569-9b74-dc1a50fab731"
maxAnswersQuantity: 0
text: "1"
userAnswersQuantity: 0
    1: {id: "ede54e9f-04e0-4504-99ed-1e5d3863d746", text: "2", maxAnswersQuantity: 0, userAnswersQuantity: 1,…}
```

Вот массив который приходит но опять же пока никак не отслеживается вот [файл с кодом](https://dropmefiles.com/iEGGN)

Comment: А почему бек не может ответить на submit этим общим баллом?

Comment: Ну потому что после моего отправления к ним приходят ответы а не так хаотично поэтому нужно высчитать тут общий бал и отобразить

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос и создайте минимальный воспроизводимый код. На данный момент сложно понять что как работает, потому что есть много зависимостей.